# Nested query in ElasticSearch - two levels

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the next mapping :

```
"c_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "an": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "sm": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "cr": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "c": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "e": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "s": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I need a query than gives me all the cr's when:

an.id == x and sm.id == y

I tried with :

```
{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"terms": {"_id": ["x"]}},
            {"nested":{"path": "sm","query":{
                        "match": {"sm.id":"y"}}}}]}}}
```

But runs very slow and gives more info than i need.
What's the most efficient way to do that ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested query here. Also, use `filter` instead of `should` if you want to find documents matching all the queries (the exception would be if you wanted the query to affect the score, like `match` query, which is not the case here, then you could use `should` + `minimum_should_match` option)

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "_id": "x" } },
        { "term": { "sm.id": "y" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks! I tried this, and there is no error, but returns zero elements, and I am sure that there is one element for the query... 

If I do : 
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "_id": "x" } }
      ]
    }
  }
} 

Everything is OK, but the problem is when i tried to add the second term...

Comment: @mgorriz I'd suggest you try changing the type of sm.id field to `keyword`